# Add Android App in "select an action" menu

Tags: android, image, android-intent

I´m looking a way to add my app in `select an action` menu that appears when one user wants to add one picture in another app (i.e chats apps).
So, when the user selects that option, android lists the apps like camera, gallery, and others.
Well, i want to appear in that menu. i know it is possible (intents, intents filters ?), but I couldn`t get the answer :(.
thanks, and sorry for my baad-bad english :$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding yourself to the menu can be done as outlined [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341368/trying-to-provide-an-image-for-apps-calling-get-contet-intent). Actually providing a response can be done as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306763/activity-return-a-image).